# How to run reload current image from disk automatically

Tags: image, 2d

I am using Blender 2.8.

I loaded a video file as background image in the 2D Animation mode, and want to draw some strokes to trace the video.
But when I change the current frame, the video image doesn't update to current frame. In the Properties Object Data window, 
The number left to the Frames changes.

I need to click the "Reload current image from disk" button right to the video path to draw the current frame in the video.
Auto Refresh options is selected.

What I want is when I changed the current frame, the video changes the frame automatically.

[image]